# Displaying "negative" time periods with Joda-Time PeriodFormatter

Tags: java, jodatime, periodformatter

I'm using joda-time (1.6.2) on a project and one of the things I'm doing is getting the difference between a predicted time and an actual time.  Sometimes this difference is positive, sometimes negative.  While the appropriate approach may be to use a `Duration` rather than a `Period`, using a `PeriodFormatter` to display the result led me a question about the PeriodFormatterBuilder class.  As an example:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 17, 13, 13, 5, 0) ;
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 17, 10, 17, 3, 0) ;

Period negativePeriod = new Period(d1, d2);
Period positivePeriod = new Period(d2, d1);

PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendHours()
    .appendSuffix(":")
    .rejectSignedValues(true) // Does this do anything?
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSuffix(":")
    .appendSeconds()
    .toFormatter();

System.out.printf("Negative Period: %s\n", pf.print(negativePeriod));
System.out.printf("Positive Period: %s\n", pf.print(positivePeriod));
```

The output of this is:

```
Negative Period: -02:-56:-02
Positive Period: 02:56:02
```

I understand that `Period` stores each component of its date and time separately, but to me, the expected behavior  of the `.rejectSignedValues(true)` method for building a `Formatter` would be to only show the `-` sign for only the first element like:

```
Negative Period: -02:56:02
```

Am I misunderstanding the API, or is this a bug?  JodaStephen?  Anyone?

The work around to display what I want is not hard, but I'm just curious about the Builder approach.

Thanks,
-Manuel

Comment: A negative periods like negative frequencies don't make much sense in the real world.  JodaTime should take the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Peter, however, this is not a period as in 1/frequency.  In Joda-Time, a `Period` is a difference between two points in time.  Surely a difference can be greater than or less than zero.

Comment: I would have called that an Interval which is supported by JodaTime.  A period is something recurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc for `rejectSignedValues` says `Reject signed values when parsing the next and following appended fields`, ie. it only affects parsing, not printing.

Your proposal might make a useful enhancement, but there is no guarantee that all components would be positive, or all negative. This is also a valid period: `P-6D8H` (a mixture of positive and negative).

Comment: Aha.  Thanks, Stephen.  You know, I read that in the Javadoc, but apparently it didn't register.  RTFMC (Carefully).  I'll just use a `Duration` for the difference (that's what I really want anyway), get the `standardSeconds`, check for sign, create a `Period` from the `Duration` of the abs(seconds) and build the `PeriodFormatter` based on the sign.  Unless there's a better way to format `Duration`?  Thanks again and keep up the great work.  I'm curious how you'd create a period `P-6D8H` (+/-mixture) from two `DateTime`s  I can only manage a `P6D8H` and a `P-6D-8H.`  But, I'll keep working.

Comment: Perhaps then a suitable convention would be: a sign is carried to the next field by default, until it is explicitly reversed. I.e., `P-3D2H` would mean "three days and two hours in the past" whereas `P-3D+2H` would mean "two hours later than three days in the past".  Of course I shudder at the backward incompatibility of that...

Answer (score 0):

I solve negative like this:

```
 Duration dToFormat = duration;
    if (duration.getStandardMinutes() < 0) {
        dToFormat = duration.minus(duration).minus(duration);
    }

    ...

    if (duration.getStandardMinutes() < 0) {
                return "-"+pf.print(p); // leading minus
            }
```

and all code here in my case:

```
public static String durationToHHHmmFormat(Duration duration, String separator){
        if ( duration == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Duration dToFormat = duration;
        if (duration.getStandardMinutes() < 0) {
            dToFormat = duration.minus(duration).minus(duration);
        }

        Period p = dToFormat.toPeriod();
        PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2) // gives the '01'
            .appendHours()
            .appendSeparator(separator)
            .appendMinutes()
            .toFormatter();

        if (duration.getStandardMinutes() < 0) {
            return "-"+pf.print(p); // leading minus
        }
        return pf.print(p);
    }
```